# Usage of "how come"

Tags: word-usage

Does "how come" replace "how can you" in these phrases:

> "How come you find the love of your life and walk away?"
>
> "How come you win the lottery and gamble all the money away?"

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. Usually, 'how come' is considered to be a synonym for 'why', but 'why' does not fit very well with the rest of the sentence without quite a bit of writing, so 'how can you' is a reasonable alternative. Or you could say something like:

> Why is it that you find the love of your life and walk away?

'How come' and 'how comes' have a long heritage ([Edmund Spenser, 1611](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-come-we-say-how-come)), but are considered informal and colloquial. It is probably a shortened version of something like "how did it come about that".